# Color coding stacked barplots by groups in R using barplot()

Tags: r, bar-chart

My goal is to create a stacked barplot in R from a matrix, where each column in the matrix is a bar with a different color, and each bar represents the sum of all rows in the column.

Here's dummy data and bar plot scripts I'm using to trouble shoot:

```
m = matrix(1:9, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
v = matrix(c("red", "blue", "green"), ncol=3, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
m #matrix of values
v #matrix of colors for each point
```

If I only plot row 1, colors are assigned correctly

`barplot(m[1,], col=v[1,])`

If I plot rows 1-3 w/o designating colors, data is stacked correctly:

`barplot(m[c(1:3),])`

If I plot rows 1-3 with BESIDE=TRUE, color codes correctly (but obviously is not stacked)

`barplot(m[c(1:3),], col=v[c(1:3),], beside = TRUE)`

If I attempt to plot rows 1-3, data stacks correctly, but color coding is not applied as needed:

`barplot(m[c(1:3),], col=v[c(1:3),])`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ultimately I want to color code bars in groups, such as the bars 1-5 are blue, bars 6-10 are green, etc., thus the term "groups" in my post title.  I'm trying to produce a plot similar to the one in the following post, but with each bar being stacked, representing three data points (aka 3 rows of a column):  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17264765/29955156-593119c0-8e92-11e7-8ad7-e76a2700bb30.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
v <- c("red","blue","green")
barplot(m, col=v, beside=FALSE)
```

Each row of your data matrix will take on a single color

Comment: Thanks for the help- but what I'm actually looking for is each **column** in my matrix to take on a single color.  What your code plots is a separate color for each "stack" across all bars.  I need a plot to look like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17264765/29955070-886f58a6-8e91-11e7-8ca1-5bdf16bfb1c3.png) but with stacked bars.

Comment: Do you still want stack lines to be visible? Or a single bar for each category is fine?